# Is there a way to change corner radius of UITableView in insetGrouped style?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swiftui, uikit

**Like This-**

[image]

Has anyone been in a similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final class InsetsGroupedCell: UITableViewCell {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        InsetsGroupedLayer.self
    }
}

final class InsetsGroupedLayer: CALayer {

    override var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get { 16 }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set cornerRadius of your tableview's Layer and set maskToBounds property to true

```
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: thanks. but i want to change sections corner, i set cell's layer to make this work

Comment: You can create tableview header and footer with your desired height and create a custom view for this header and footer. Then define your own corner radius for this custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Use grouped style instead of insetGrouped.